# How to expose MongoDB data through an OData API ( ORM? )

Tags: .net, mongodb, odata

I am aware of the "long" way to do this, wiring up all of the CRUD methods.  Just wondering if there is a piece of software / library / ORM or some way to fast track this..?

I would hate to write this app and then find out I wasted weeks doing it manually!